# How to complete the proof that $A^c\cup(A\setminus B)=(A\cap B)^c$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I had to prove that:
For all sets A and B, $A^c \cup (A \setminus B) = (A \cap B)^c$. 

Below is what I did, but I'm kind of stuck at the time.

So I begin with proving $A^c \cup (A \setminus B) \subseteq (A \cap B)^c$.
Let $x \in A^c \cup (A \setminus B)$. 
Note, by DeMorgan's law, $(A \cap B)^c$ = $A^c \cup B^c$.
Then, $x \in A^c$ or $x \in A$ and $x \notin B$. 
If $x \in A^c$, then $x \in A^c \cup B^c$. 
If $x \in (A \setminus B)$, then $x \in A$ and $x \in B^c$, thus $x \in A^c \cup B^c$.

Left is to prove $(A \cap B)^c \subseteq A^c \cup (A \setminus B)$. 
Let $x \in A^c \cup B^c$. 
Then, $x \in A^c$ or $x \in B^c$. 
If $x \in A^c$ then $x \in A^c \cup (A \setminus B)$. 
If $x \in B^c$ then ..?

I don't think you can now say that $x \in A \setminus B$, can you? I considered coming up with a counterexample as I couldn't figure out what I'm missing, but I can't seem to find one.

Any help is appreciated!
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** Now consider the two cases, either $x\in A$ or it isn't. One of them you dealt with. What does the other give you?

---

**Full answer:** (After indication from the comments that the hint was understood) if $x\in B^c$ then either $x\in B^c$ and $x\in A^c$, in which case we already know that $x\in A^c\cup(A\setminus B)$, or $x\in B^c$ and $x\in A$, in which case $x\in A\setminus B$ and the proof is completed.

Comment: If $x \in A$, obviously $x \in A \setminus B$.

Comment: Yes. And if it is not?

Comment: If $x \notin A$, then $x \notin A \setminus B$. How do I get to this from $x \in B^c$? I believe I have to show that $x \notin A$ and $x \notin B$, but I can only show the latter.

Comment: First of all, $x\notin A$ can also be written as? Secondly, you have that $x\in A$ or $x\notin A$. Regardless to $x\in B^c$, you just do a case by case analysis.

Comment: $x \notin A$ can be written as $x \in A^c$. Sorry if my questions are trivial, but I don't see why we have to consider them separately (because of the brackets). I thought we have to consider two cases: (1): $x \in A^c$ and (2): $x \in A$ and $x \notin B$.

Comment: That is what you have to show. You started by assuming $x\in(A\cap B)^c$. Then you did case by case analysis and got stuck at $x\in B^c$. My hint for you is that $B^c=B^c\cap(A\cup A^c)$.

Comment: @Alexei If $x\in B^{c}$, then there are exactly two possible cases: $x\in A$, $x\in A^{c}$. You have already checked the $x\in A^{c}$ case (just without the constraint $x\in B^{c}$). What is left to check is what happens if $x\in A$. What happens is $(x\in A)\land (x\in B^{c})$, i.e. $x\in A\cap B^{c}$, i.e. $x\in A\setminus B$, and this is what we wanted to prove.

Comment: Ah! Reading mathh's comment I understand it now :). Thanks alot, it was not that hard after all!